# XMPP Message not delivered at openfire

Tags: xmpp, netty, openfire, smack

Earlier I was using smack as the client side library and sending the message to the openfire and it was working properly.

Now I want to use netty along with smack to establish the connection. I am able to create the channel and openfire shows me the connection created but I am not able to send the Registration  packet to the openfire. I am writing the packet on the channel but its not getting delivered at the openfire.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use wireshark to see if the XMPP packets are been delivered.
If not you need to check your code.